# Perform a mouse click after 5 seconds when a particular web link is the foreground tab in chrome

Tags: javascript

I want to perform a mouse click `5 seconds after` a particular web page is in the foreground tab of the Chrome browser. Code for the mouse click is `document.querySelector('[value="submit"]').click()` and Web link is `www.website.com`
Please guide me if this arrangement will be possible. Regards, Vicky.

@Maik Lowrey, The page is already opened in the chrome browser, say in the second tab. Now when I move to that second tab (bring it to the foreground) , I want to wait for 5 seconds and emulate a mouse click on the search button there. This is what I want to achieve. (I can't reply to your comment, so editing here)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't quite understand your question. Do you want to submit a form after 5 seconds after the DOM is loaded? Or call a JS function?

Comment: @VickyLahkar I reviewed your suggested edit to add a reply to Maik's comment. If you log in on the same account that posted the question, you will be able to put your response in the comments where it belongs. Also, I suggest that you have your accounts merged. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Do you have control over both pages? The one in the foreground and the one where you want to trigger the click?

Answer (score 1):

To detect either the tab have become visible or hidden, you can use the [visibilitychange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) and use the visibilityState to access the state itself. Then you can use the setTimeout function to run the submit event and set the time out to 5000 miliseconds.

```
function fireTheSubmitEvent() {
   document.querySelector('[value="submit"]').click()
}

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    setTimeout(fireTheSubmitEvent, 5000)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got this correct with this code:

```
if(document.referrer=="w-w-w.website.url") {
  function fireTheSubmitEvent() {
     setTimeout(fireTheSubmitEvent, 2000)
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
      document.querySelector('[value="Search"]').click()
    }
  })
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).